# Why am I not seeing files after downloading FontAwesome nuget package?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, font-awesome

I recently downloaded the FontAwesome 5.2.0 NuGet package [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Font.Awesome/). After installing the package, nothing has changed but an updated line in my .csproj file. Am I missing a step? I then stumbled upon this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/bower?view=aspnetcore-2.0). It seems client side packages are suited for bower package manager but the FontAwesome guys have one available via nuget.org.

Visual Studio 2017 Version: 15.5.7

My development enviornment is offline on an intranet so I have to transfer whatever files I need. I cannot install them via the internet.

Comment: fontawesome is available as an npm package, bower is out of style now. you need a package.json file which is what npm uses. afaik in asp.net core nuget packages do not deliver content files into your project and is not the recommended way to get client side dependencies

Comment: or download the zip https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/fontawesome-free-5.2.0-web.zip

Comment: @JoeAudette If it doesn't deliver content files then why would they have it out there? See my confusion?

Comment: nugets used to deliver content in older asp.net but in asp.net core they moved away from that for client side stuff. it may work as nuget has been updated several times since when I found it did not work for aspnet core, but is still not recommended. if you add the nuget and it doesn't bring in the files then I guess it doesn't work. in any case not recommended way to get client side stuff.

Comment: @JoeAudette We figured it out. I think my teammate is going to post the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you install the package, you can open C:/USER.HOME/.nuget/packages and find the fontawesome dir. Inside the "content" dir. is all the files and they can be manaully imported into the project.

Answer (score 0):

For me running `Update-Package FontAwesome -reinstall` is what helped (files first installed in `%username%/.nuget` but then moved to the correct location)